# Is it possible to gather unit test list & results on SonarQube 4.5?

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to gather and extract information about unit tests analysed by sonar such as : test name, status, test case ran ...
I wonder if I can get this via the REST API ? an dif yes, how can I do such a thing ?

I am able to find all issues related to unit test with the filter "?rules=" but that doesn't quite fit my needs.
Actually, sonar only rises one issue per file with failed test and I have no other informations such as which test cases fail or anything. Am I doing something wrong or what I want is simply not available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible thanks to the "/api/tests/show" API WS.

- See the [online documentation](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation#api/tests)
- See a [live example on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/tests/show?key=org.apache.activemq%3Aactivemq-runtime-config%3Asrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fapache%2Factivemq%2FNetworkConnectorTest.java)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what I wanted was to gather information on every test run without knowing its name, with "/tests/show" I have to specify the testname I want to visualize.
What I want is to be able to parse all the tests programmatically and extract information I need from it.

Comment: If you do some effort, you will find a WS to list all the test files of a project ("/api/resources/index?qualifiers=UTS&depth=-1&resource=MyProjectKey"), and then you can iterate on each file to call the WS that I gave you.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I tried to get =)

Comment: 8 years later I am looking for the same information with sonarqube 8. with the "/api/tests/show" I just get a "{"errors":[{"msg":"Unknown url : /api/resources/index"}]}". Any suggestions? - Thanks