# Sonarqube python plugin unit test drilldown

Tags: python, unit-testing, sonarqube, nosetests

I have a python project analyzed with sonarqube, my project has some unit test inside it runned with nosetest, the sonarqube runner reads the XML generated by nose and shows me the statistic of the test (number of test, success, errors, failed and skipped).

When i click on the number of errors it redirects me to a page with the sources of the test and show me the number of test with error per file. Here is a picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfh8X.png

Also if i call the rest API of sonarqube to get the result of unit test following this question in stackoverflow: [Is it possible to gather unit test list & results on SonarQube 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545754/is-it-possible-to-gather-unit-test-list-results-on-sonarqube-4-5) i get all the information of each unit test (errors, traceback, etc...).

But i cant find this information (name of the unit test with errors, what is the error, trackebacks... Some kind of logs) inside sonarqube dashboard, after some test i've found this video: https://vimeo.com/5577540 so i think sonarqube can do it, but i dont seem to find the way.

Im using sonarqube 5.1.2 and python plugin 1.5

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the SonarQube Python plugin. I created a [ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPY-135) to improve that in a later version.